# how to make point on two intersected edge?

Tags: intersection

[image]

Can you tell me how to set the point on the two intersecting paths?

I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and enter but nothing happens.

Comment: From the hilights in the outliner, it looks as if you're editing two seperate objects (Plane and Circle) at once. If so you won't be able to create a vertex joining the edges until you've actually joined the objects into one with Ctrl-J in Object mode first.

Comment: @JohnEason , Thanks ! it's really important point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possibility is to use "Auto merge" and "Split edges and faces" options.

Once done hit <kbd>G</kbd> and validate the grab without moving the mouse.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I sovled the issue !

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to lemon's solution there is an addon called tinyCAD that comes bundled with Blender.
It can get you all edge intersections with 'XAll'.
[image]